# How to list key in Amazon S3 with wildcard

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

As AWS website, see [this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html#workloads-with-mix-request-types), AWS mention that key name on S3 should be named with hashed or random sequence of hex value in order to optimize performance of how S3 actually store data, eg.

- /bucket-name/a2f0/test/001.txt
- /bucket-name/83de/test/002.txt
- /bucket-name/c1aa/test/003.txt

As they mentioned in website about listing key with prefix like '[0-f][0-f][0-f][0-f]/test/', but I have tried, using Python library Boto and `'s3cmd ls [prefix]'`, and it was failed to list those 3 files above.

Is there anyway to list key with this kind of wildcard ?

Answer (score 0):

These days, it is recommended to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) instead of `s3cmd`.

To list the objects, you would need to **include the name of the bucket**, eg:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucketname/
```

This would show the full path for the 3 objects:

```
a2f0/test/001.txt
83de/test/002.txt
c1aa/test/003.txt
```

Also, please note that the recommendation for prefixing Amazon S3 objects with a randomly distributed hash is only required when performing a **large number of operations** (eg creating more than 100 objects per second). You might want to try using S3 without the hash to see if it meets your performance requirements, before trying to use the hash method.